# How to resume chat window with previous chats in android?

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I am working on a chat application using smack api in android. I am succeeded in chatting with one user. But I want to display the chat window of same user with previous chats each time like skype or whtas app so user can see his/her previous chats.
How to achieve this?
What should I do. . crate database or what??
I am using Openfire server.
Please give me a proper solution to achieve this.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to store the data somewhere, and the most logical place is a database. For `Android` apps, you can use a local `SQLite` database as this is probably a non-relevant data to be stored in a central data base, so in a local database should be enough. Each time you reopen your window, simply query the last lines and place it once you open your window.

You might want to have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).